LyX 2.4: How to paste text without line breaks?
Before LyX 2.4, the default "copy text from elsewhere and paste in LyX" behavior was to kill any line breaks.
Now in LyX 2.4, the default behavior is to preserve the line breaks (which is great).
But now, is there any way to paste the text without the line breaks (i.e. get the old behavior)?
(This Q is the "opposite" of this Q.)

Edit > Paste Special > Plain Text (Join Lines):

On my OS (Linux), this is bound to ctrl + alt + shift + v, however this default keybinding can change depending on the OS.
You are right that this change of behavior is intended. When LyX makes a "major" release (e.g., from 2.3.x to 2.4.0) that is the chance to break a few things, or change defaults, that are thought to be better in the long-run.
